# Gerund or participle

Tags: grammar

We took skiing vacation .
We saw a skiing monkey.

In the above  2 sentences the word "SkIING" confuse me. Plz help me in the first sentence is the word playing the role of gerund or participle?

Answer (score 2):

In the first, it is a gerund. In the second, it is a participle.

This is because in the first, "skiing" takes the place of an adjectival noun. The vacation is not skiing, the vacation is *for* skiing.

In the second, the monkey *is* actually skiing.

Comment: Unless they find a new a species of monkey and call it *skiiing* . . . Then things could get confusing. ;)

Comment: @JasonBassford !!!!